# iphone: UIImagePickerController how to get the thumbnail for the picker control

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, thumbnails

Hello I need to use the uiimagepickercontroller to get the photo from the photo library in IOS 3. I managed to get the original image and custom coding to generate the thumbnail from the original image.

Is there a way of fetching the thumbnail that was used in the UIImagePickerController? I can generate thumbnail from original image but it will slow down the whole process. At the time, is there a way of saving the url of the original image. At the moment, I am just create a new image and saved on a temporary folder for later app to upload the server. The process is too slow since I need to generate thumbnail as well as creating the original image.

Answer (score 0):

in ios 3.0 , their is no direct way to get thumbnail, you have to do custom coding to get thumbnail .
from version 4.0 we have  ALAssetsLibrary.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetslibrary = [self defaultAssetsLibrary];

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){    
              CGImageRef thumbnailRef = [myasset thumbnail]; //gives thumbnail 
        }

[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl  resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                          //handle error
                   }];
```

but cons of above method is if used declined access to library then you have to handle error and again get thumbnail again with custom coding .

please update if you have find any better method .